# What does "ack" at the start of a sentence mean?

Tags: sens

I've seen various people writing comments in French start their sentence with "Ack".  In English this would be an exclamation of surprise or difficulty, but it seems to be used differently in French.  I can't put my finger on how exactly, though.  What does it mean?

---

J'ai régardé des gens qui commencent leur phrases françaises avec "ack".  En anglais c'est une exclamation de surprise ou de difficulté mais on a l'impression que c'est utilisé différemment en français.  Cependant je ne peux pas mettre le doigt sur le sens exact.  Qu'est-ce que cela signifie?

Comment: If they are computer scientists, this can mean : *OK bien reçu*, for **ack**nowledged. Sinon, je vois pas.

Comment: Are you sure you're not mishearing "Faque" (a particle frequent in Quebec speech)?

Comment: No I've seen it at the beginning of comments on Youtube.

Comment: Can you post an example or a link to an example?

Comment: @Jez I've never heard or read that. If it's not for *acknowledgement*, it must be related to the channel. An example would be nice.

Comment: If it's on Youtube, it's on the Internet. What I mean is that we tend to use more and more English/US expression, that we learn while playing online, watching videos, or even a meme (check "ack meme") etc. That could be it. If you find a comment (giving context) it maybe help. I'm maybe too old, but that could be also an SMS abbreviation (made me think of "à ce qu'il parait", but seems to be "askip").

Comment: Please add a link or screenshot for context, especially if you saw it on a public YouTube video

Comment: @jcm69 I've been in IT for almost 20 years and I can't recall having used or seen this form be used so it's definitely not something usual even for developers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selon une recherche sur Google :

ACK : Abréviation du mot anglais ACKnowledged (« reconnu ») ou de ACKnowledgement (« accusé de réception »).

Selon Livio l'antonyme est NACK.

Voir aussi :

https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/ack.html

http://www.dicofr.com/cgi-bin/n.pl/dicofr/definition/20010101000005

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abr%C3%A9viations_militaires_(Belgique)